# How to draw bezier path around a concave white portion of black-and-white image?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, opencv, opencv3.0

I need to find the contour of a black and white image and draw a bezier path around the white portion in a black and white image, the white portion is concave, is there a way to get a bezier path around the white portion, wrapping the entire white portion on it's boundary?